How do I stream output as it is being generated by an LLM in Streamlit?
code:

from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
import streamlit as st
from HtmlTemplates import bot_template , user_template , css
import torch

def set_prompt():
    custom_prompt_template = """[INST] <<SYS>>
    You are a trained to guide people about Indian Law. You will answer user's query with your knowledge and use context provided.
    Do not say thank you and tell you are an AI Assistant and be open about everything.
    Always complete the sentence you are generating
    <</SYS>>
    Use the following pieces of context to answer the users question.
    Context : {context}
    Question : {question}
    Answer : [/INST]
    """

    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=custom_prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"])
    return prompt


def retrieval_qa_chain(llm, prompt, db):
    qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type='stuff',
        retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 6}),
        chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': prompt}
    )

    return qa_chain

def qa_pipeline():
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = 'multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1' , model_kwargs = {'device': device})

    db = FAISS.load_local("vectorstore", embeddings , allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)

    llm = LlamaCpp(model_path = path,
                   temperature = temperature,
                   n_ctx = 2048,
                   n_batch = 128,
                   n_gpu_layers = -1,
                   max_tokens = max_tokens,
                   verbose = False )
    print(path)
    qa_prompt = set_prompt()

    chain = retrieval_qa_chain(llm, qa_prompt, db)
    return chain

def handle_user_input(user_question):
    with st.spinner("Generating response ..."):
            response = chain(user_question)
            response = response['result']
    st.write(bot_template.replace("{{MSG}}",response),unsafe_allow_html=True)
        

st.set_page_config(page_title = "Your personal Law ChatBot", page_icon = ":bot:")
st.write(css , unsafe_allow_html=True)

global chain, path, temperature, max_tokens

with st.sidebar:
    model = st.selectbox("Select Model :",("Llama2 7b (Faster)" , "Llama2 13b (Can answer complex queries)"))
    if model == 'Llama2 13b (Can answer complex queries)':
        path = "Models/llama-2-13b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf"

    elif model == 'Llama2 7b (Faster)':
        path = "Models/llama-2-7b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf"
    temperature = st.slider(label="Temperature",
              min_value=0.1,
              max_value=1.0,
              value=0.3,
              step=0.05
              )
    max_tokens = st.slider(label="Max Tokens",
              min_value=256,
              max_value=4096,
              value=1024,
              step=64
              )

if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
  st.session_state.chat_history = []

st.header("Your personal Law ChatBot :books:")

user_question = st.chat_input("Ask a question :")
chain = qa_pipeline()

if user_question:
  st.write(user_template.replace("{{MSG}}",user_question),unsafe_allow_html=True)
  handle_user_input(user_question)

for chat in st.session_state.chat_history:
   st.write(user_template.replace("{{MSG}}",chat["User"]),unsafe_allow_html=True)
   st.write(bot_template.replace("{{MSG}}",chat["Bot"]),unsafe_allow_html=True)


In this, when the output is completely generated, only then is its displayed.
Is there a way that it can be streamed on Streamlit, while it is being generated?
I tried the StreamingStdCallbackHandler() from LangChain but it only streams in command line.
I want to get the ChatGPT like effect.
I want it to happen in Streamlit web page.

use st.write_stream()
you can find the docs here

I know about that function but the thing is that streams the output after the whole text is generated by the llm. I want to stream while it is being generated

To solve this issue mentioned in the comment, You can use a generator function and use the streaming API of your LLM Orchestration library (in my case llama-index).
import streamlit as st

from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI

llm = OpenAI(
    model="gpt-4",
    api_base="http://0.0.0.0:8080/v1",
    api_key="",
    max_tokens=1024,
    temperature=0.1,
)


def chat(question):
    response = llm.stream_complete(question)
    for resp in response:
        yield resp.delta


question = st.text_input(label="what's up?")
if question:
    st.write_stream(chat(question=question))

(Note that I'm not actually using GPT4, I use a local LLM with OpenAI Compatible Server using llama-cpp-python which is the reason why I can use the OpenAI Wrapper)
